# Why does SubSonic 2.0 use System.Data.SQLite version 1.0.60.0?

Tags: .net, sqlite, subsonic, subsonic2.2

Anyone know why Subsonic 2.2 uses System.Data.SQLite version 1.0.60.0 instead of the latest version 1.0.65.0? ie is it just because that's when it was released or is there anything in the newer version that doesn't work with SubSonic?

What does everyone else use - do you just recompile from the latest branch of SubSonic using the latest System.Data.SQLite?

Comment: I am guessing that most people have moved on to Subsonic 3.0 now if they are continuing to use the product. I have not checked but it probably has support for the latest SQLite.

Comment: yeah, i guess you're right, but sadly no support for .NET 2.0 :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason other than it's not a priority to keep things up to date. If you were to work on the subsonic2 source project with sqlite you would probably increase the developer count by 100%.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to check out subsonic2-trunk and recompile it with the latest version of Sqlite. I think (correct me if I'm wrong) the subsonic unit tests only check MSSQL and MySQL so you have to manuelly test if everything works fine.

However you could also use the manifest file to "redirect" the dependency to a newer version of Sqlite: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx without getting the source.